# Proposed method to reduce nuisance phone calls

Tags: encryption, identity

I'm getting annoyed with tons of nuisance phone calls. Most are scams. Most want you to listen to a recording, so I don't even have the satisfaction of calling them names, or leading them down the garden path.

I think there is, and that it could actually be done for under a buck a phone line.

The problem then falls into two parts:

It should be unreasonably hard to spoof a phone number. It may be possible, as a service,  to hide a number, but not to pretend to be someone else.

The services part is easy, and can be done by each telco individually. The no spoof requires a common protocol.

Would the following work?

For this discussion we will consider an exchange to be a block of 10,000 numbers -- the last 4 digits of each phone number.  Historically this was a single building in a community.  Now, I'm sure there are multiple exchanges hosted in a single location.

Suppose that every exchange generated a public/private key pair for each line.

When Alice phones Bob, Alice's exchange (AX, from now on) encrypts Alice's number, Alices ID string, bob's number, and a timestamp with Alice's private key. Bob's exchange (BX) requests Alices public key from AX, and uses it to decrypt the message. This verifies that Alice's phone number is genuine, and uses Alices official ID string to show up on Bob's phone, unless Alice choses to not display them.

At this BX looks at what Alice allows to be displayed, and what Bob is willing to accept.  Only if Bob's options are compatible with Alice's options does Bob's phone ring.

This reaches my phone along with the first ring, or depending on my options, a message on my voice mail, or a message saying that I don't accept messages from unidentified callers.

Is this workable?

I realize that I can't do anything about this myself, but with a valid workable (in principle) method, and I can keep squeaking at my Telco until they come up with a method to banish these calls.

A standard exchange has 10,000 numbers, although frequently many are unused. How much computing power would it take, if the whole initial hand shake has to take under, say, 2 seconds? (Reasonable assumption: In a residential exchange there is an average of, what, 20 calls per line per day? so 20,000 calls. On the average that's 1 every 4 seconds. Assume they show major clustering, and have peak densities 100 times as great. That's 25 per second. I think that a 486 with a pair of 100 MB ethernet ports could handle this aspect of it. Comments?

Once spoofing a number is hard, then the telco can offer some new services:

- "No Number, No ring" If you don't provide caller your, my phone doesn't even ring.  Optionally my telco can say, "Your caller doesn't accept no-number calls.  Press *12 to send your number, *13 to send your number and caller id."
- "No ID, No ring." More stringent than the last, the number has to resolve to a real identity on the calling exchange database. This database would be kept by the phone company.  The client who has the number sets the ID text to be displayed.  The phone company would vet this to keep someone from claiming to be someone else.  Joe's Collection Agency cannot have an ID that is "New York Lottery Commission"
- Variants on this would be "direct to voice mail" with a customizable voice mail saying that you don't accept anonymous calls in person.
- A phone number #SPAM that says that the previous call on my line was an unwanted nuisance call. For this, your number is recorded as well as the nuisance number.  Your number is counted only once.  When a number gets more than N #spam tags, the tagged number is blocked.  This is recorded by my local exchange, and forwarded to the originating exchange.

Comment: The phone company.  The owner of the phone number can determine what text he wants displayed.  This could be in the same database as the keys.

Comment: #SPAM:  Your number is recorded as well as the target number.  You are only counted once.  To do DoS you have to receive a phone call from your target at many different phone numbers.  A telemarketer is making scores to hundreds of calls per hour.  The occasional #spam when you woke someone up with a hangover isn't going to deny you service.  Nor will a teenage girl's dad be able to stop her scruffy boyfriend by hitting #spam each time he takes a call -- that's only 1 'vote'

Comment: You need to understand that the politicians support these calls so there is little hope.

Comment: A ray of home here:  https://sites.atis.org/insights/new-specification-atis-sip-forum-advances-network-capabilities-mitigate-unwanted-robocalling-caller-id-fraud/

Comment: I don't really think this is a good fit for StackOverflow...

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for a better forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. It's also too broad and primarily opinion oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Nuisance calls can annoy you very much. The one who gets plagued with these types of calls knows how it feels to be in such situations. 
Certain tips are listed below that you can follow to get rid of these calls:

1. **Report a nuisance call**: When you receive unwanted calls, there are a number of companies that you may refer to register a complaint. Be aware of the companies and stop these calls yourself.
   You can contact your telephone operator or the TPS and report the caller.
2. **Register with the TPS**: When you are overwhelmed with the unsolicited calls and not able to find a way out, you can register with the TPS. TPS is the Telephone Preference service that will take an action on your behalf and that too free of cost.
3. **Talk to your phone company**: If you have tried the above methods and are still receiving the nuisance calls, you should contact your phone company as soon as possible and report the caller.
4. **Block the calls**: There are various companies that offer services that let you block the unwanted callers. Some of these companies offer to block services for free, while with others, you may have to pay some monthly charges.

These were certain ways to prevent the nuisance calls. Use them and keep yourself and your family safe.

If you want to read more steps to prevent spam calls with proper strategies then click **[here](https://www.reverseafrica.com/)**.